# Angular 2 - param missing for sub-sub-route

Tags: angular, routes

I find it really hard to make a sub sub route parameter work

these first 2 levels work fine

```
http://localhost:8080/#/customer/4/
http://localhost:8080/#/customer/4/campaign/13
http://localhost:8080/#/customer/4/campaign/13/segments
```

but once I try this one

```
http://localhost:8080/#/customer/4/campaign/13/segment/1
```

the third parameter /1 is not populated so I cant use it

```
this.activatedRoute.parent.params.subscribe((params: any) => {
                    let customerId = +params['id'];   <<< present
                    let campaignId = +params['cid'];  <<< present
                    let segmentId = +params['sid'];   <<< NaN !!!!
                    ....
                });
```

Here is my routing setup

```
const customersRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'customer/:id',
      canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
      children: [
        { path: '', component: CustomerComponent },
        { path: 'campaign/:cid', component: CustomerCampaignComponent ,
          children:[
            { path: 'segments', component: SegmentsComponent },
            { path: 'segment/:sid', component: SegmentComponent },
            ]
        },
      ]
    }
];
```

Anyone know how I could fix this ?

thanks

Comment: if you manually type the url with the 3rd parameter, does it work or not?

Comment: it routes correctly, but the last id never gets into the params array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Assuming that you are in `SegmentComponent`*

`sid` does not exist in the parent route but exists in the route itself.

```
this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params: any) => {
     let segmentId = +params['sid'];                    ....
 });
```

You can [merge](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/merge.html) the observables as below :

```
let obs = this.activatedRoute.params.combineLatest(this.activatedRoute.parent.params)
obs.subscribe(...)
```

Comment: another angular 2 router oddity, how comes when I surf to the parent route, I manage to get the cid ? I should have the same problem...anyway, thx, I'll merge these two streams  :-)

Comment: It's a good question. Normally you have to encounter the same problem in `CustomerCampaignComponent`

Comment: actualy merge does not merge both values while combineLatest does...I tried concat too, but it only returns one value

Answer (score 0):

I combined both params like this but as Radouane mentioned one could do it otherwise

```
 this.activatedRoute.params.combineLatest(this.activatedRoute.parent.params,(val1, val2) => {
                  console.dir(val1);
                  console.dir(val2);
                  return {val1: val1, val2: val2};
                })
                .subscribe(res => { console.dir(res)});
```